# Fixing a door's edge properly

Tags: technique, restoration, wood-repair

I have a corner hutch with a typical top half which has the top half glass and the bottom have a set of solid doors. Here's a pic:

[image]

I did some restoration on this a few years ago and saved it from getting painted by the previous owner (who'd do that to wood, right?) While this job was not a perfect restoration or anything, I did get it back to the point where the wood showed and the stain was fairly even. It took me quite a while to get it back into shape.

One of the things which has always bugged me is, the doors at the bottom have some damage on them which is mainly on the inside, so isn't readily seen. What Is there a specific way in which I should try to repair them? Is there a way to patch them, or do I need to replace the wood? Here are a pictures of the damage:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unrelated...is that floor Brazillian Cherry, by any chance?

Comment: @JeromyFrench - Absolutely. Solid. Micro-bevel. Tongue-n-groove. 5/8x3.5", I believe.

Comment: On a historical note: Wood (mainly pine) was frequently decoratively painted around the Georgian (King George III) and Regency periods in the UK. There has also been plenty of 'wood graining' of furniture using paints and varnishes. Back in the 1980's though it became fashionable to sell stripped pine furniture (my father had a shop in London at the time) huge amounts of which were exported to the US and Europe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the defect were in a location that was not subject to wear and abuse, you could fill the defect with wood putty.  After it cured, you could sand it down, and finish to taste.  Unfortunately, this location will get beat up further, and the wood putty would just chip off.

A better possibility is to make a "patch" out of a similar piece of wood.  Trim away just enough of the existing wood that you have a good, clean surface, with a regular enough shape that you can make a complementary patch.  Shape the patch to match, so that the patch stands slightly proud.  Attach the patch, probably with glue.  Sand down the patch to smoothly match the piece.  Finish to taste.

Comment: It actually looks like both of these techniques would work from the photo.  There looks to be two boards from the photo - the board to the right is going to need to be patched with new wood and the stain matched.  The other board may be salvageable with some sanding and filler.

Comment: @Jasper I would suggest (based on my own experience) that when fitting the patch into the space created that it should not be fitted proud as sanding it down will expose fresh, unoxidised, wood which will really 'glow' when trying to match colours. I'd recommend sanding the raw back of the patch and aiming for a precise fit - naturally some space has to be allowed fro the thin layer of adhesive required. If the patch is being painted then it isn't an issu

Answer (score 2):

you can clean up, flatten the damage, with a sander and then glue a similar type of wood piece to it. when it is cured then reform the edge to a square appearance, you may want to mix the dust from the sanding with the glue, tightbond III to minimize the line appearance.